# ¿Cómo asignar un vector de contenido para múltiples cards de material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Soy bastante nuevo en el uso de **React** y, particularmente en el uso de **material-ui** y estoy tratando de hacer una web con **9 CardMedia** y quiero que **cada una muestre una imagen, un título y una descripción en concreto**. Ahora mismo, para crearlas itero sobre 9 pero me gustaría saber si puedo crear algún tipo de vector con la información que quiero poner según la carta que sea y donde y como declarar ese vector y como asignar el contenido en base a la iteración.

```
 <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="md">
                {/* End hero unit */}
                <Grid container spacing={4}>
                    {cards.map((card) => ( //del 1 al 9
                        <Grid item key={card} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                            <Card className={classes.card}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    //className={classes.cardMedia}
                                    src = {photo1}
                                    component={"img"} //ahora estoy asignando una imagen por defecto importada previamente
                                    title="Image title"
                                />
                                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                        Heading
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>
                                        This is a media card. You can use this section to describe the content.
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <CardActions>
                                    <Button size="large" color="secondary" >
                                        Aprender
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button size="large" color="primary">
                                        Desafío
                                    </Button>
                                </CardActions>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Container>
```

Para que se hagan una idea, la página web es similar a esta: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/album/

Comment: No sé si entiendo la pregunta, pero creo que te basta con iterar sobre un array de objetos que tenga la información que necesitas en lugar de un array de ¿números o strings?

Comment: Hola Victor, si a lo que te referis es definir en que posicion ponerla y que informacion eso seria en tu array de datos. El .map y por como tenes configurado las cards por fila, tendrias que ordenarlo antes de hacer el map.

Comment: Hola @AvedisMaroukian La posición ya la tengo. Simplemente quiero que en cada una aparezca una imagen. un título y una descripción distinta en cada tarjeta, de manera que yo pueda asignar a la primera la foto 1, descripción 1 y título 1. En la 2 la foto 2, descripción 2 y título 2 y así

Comment: @PabloLozano quiero iterar sobre las 9 tarjetas que se forman en el código que he adjuntado para que, en vez de que en todas diga lo mismo, cada una tenga un contenido diferente elegido por mi

Comment: ¿el array cards qué contiene?

Comment: @VíctorMorais entonces tendrias que hacer lo siguiente. Suponiendo que la card tiene una imagen, desripcion y titulo. En el card media tendrias que poner 

component={card.image}

En vez de poner This is a media card. You can use this section to describe the content. tendrias que poner {card.description}